# Background image opacity affects icon on top of it

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Card component from Material UI. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

You can see both: Star and Plus icon have inherited opacity from the background image.

I want the Plus icon to have `opacity 1`. Is this possible? Here is code:

```html
<Card
    style={{
        position: "relative",
    }}
>
    <IconButton
        color="primary"
        className={classes.star}
        style={{
            pointerEvents: itemEnabled ? "auto" : "none"
        }}
    >
        {item.favorite ? <Star /> : <StarBorder />}
    </IconButton>
    <IconButton
        color="primary"
        className={classes.permission}
        onClick={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            console.log("test")
        }}
    >
        <Add />
    </IconButton>
    <CardActionArea style={{
        width: "100%",
        pointerEvents: itemEnabled ? "auto" : "none"
    }}>
        <CardMedia
            className={classes.media}
            image={requiredImage}
            style={{
                opacity: itemEnabled ? 1 : 0.4,
            }}
            title={item.favorite ? item.link.name : item.name}
        />
    </CardActionArea>
</Card>
```

here are some styles used in `className` if interested:

```
const styles = theme => ({
    media: {
        height: 140,
        width: "100%"
    },
    star: {
        position: "absolute",
        right: 0,
        color: "white",
        zIndex: 555
    },
    permission: {
        position: "absolute",
        right: 0,
        top: 30,
        color: "white",
        zIndex: 555
    },
    linksTitle: {
        padding: 20
    }
});
```

Comment: The only thing you are applying opacity to appears to be CardMedia, but your button and icon are not even descendants of that - so I don’t see how these could be affected to begin with here? (But granted, it might be that I am missing something about how that terrible react syntax works.)

Comment: @04FS Yes you are right that is why I *only* set opacity to CardMedia. So I don't know why I have this problem? Don't get confused by syntax, it is either inline style used or they call it CSS in JS.

Comment: I do not see opacity on the icons but the contrast is much lower, You may add a black text-shadow on to increase contrast on the edge.

Comment: I agree with @G-Cyr here. The icons didn't inherit the opacity but its white color creates an illusion that it has opacity. You can prove it by setting the color of your Icons to black temporarily and see if it really has an opacity.

Comment: @JkAlombro I tried I increased opacity set it to 0.1 and you could see the icons were even harder to be seen

Comment: @G-Cyr check my above comment

Comment: check this example about the shadow to increase contrast on the edge  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jjxNay  If you mix white and white, you only see white , opacity means you can see through it depending on the value given .